# Can jInterface be used without nodes?

Tags: erlang, jinterface

The whole node concept in Erlang assumes that the nodes are secure.. always.  There are roundabout methods floating on how to solve this problem but no real Erlang node solution.

I am in the process of building nodes between Java and Erlang but have the problem of security.  Now I am faced with ssl over tcp/udp.  I don't want to write my own protocol (disregarding the application level protocol) if I don't have to.

Can I use jInterface to parse terms to & from an Erlang tcp/udp server if I use binary_to_term & term_to_binary on the Erlang side?

Comment: Note that I do intend to test this, just thought it was a good question.

Comment: Have you tried using `RABBITMQ` ? We found out in a recent system that had to interconnect many applications, that using such a linking mechanism provided for a good integration framework.

Comment: Actually, I have looked into Rabbit but have found many more comprehensive examples for zeromq.  From a security standpoint I think zero provides a finer grained interface and will better suit the need.  This combined with a java zero client (or Rabbit) and jInterface should allow for as little protocol code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use the library to decode terms. By the way [there exist BERT (Binary ERlang Term)](http://bert-rpc.org/) that you may use for communication.

Comment: Maybe you can help with this one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189447/jinterface-to-create-external-erlang-term