# jInterface to create External Erlang Term

Tags: java, erlang, jinterface

How can I format the the following erlang term:

```
{ atom, "message" }
```

In jInterface to an external format that I may call in an erlang shell

```
erlang:binary_to_term( Binary )
```

Example:
Note that since the tuple will be sent over the net, I finish by converting to byte[].

```
OtpErlangObject[] msg = new OtpErlangObject[2];
msg[0] = new OtpErlangAtom( "atom" );
msg[1] = new OtpErlangString( "message" );

OtpErlangTuple reply = new OtpErlangTuple(msg);

OtpOutputStream stream = new OtpOutputStream(reply);

stream.toByteArray()    // byte[] which I send over net
```

The binary received by Erlang is:

```
B = <<104,2,100,0,4,97,116,111,109,107,0,7,109,101,115,115,97,103,101>>
```

Then in an erlang shell converting the received term to binary gives a badarg.

```
 binary_to_term( B ).                                                     
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  binary_to_term/1
        called as binary_to_term(<<104,2,107,0,4,97,116,111,109,107,0,7,109,
                                   101,115,115,97,103,101>>)
```

Comment: sorry but i really can't understand your problem and what you are asking here..can you be more precise?

Comment: Why does my java jInterface code not create a complete BERT term?

Comment: why binary representation? are you working with sockets or with a java node connected to an erlang one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
binary_to_term( <<131,104,2,107,0,4,97,116,111,109,107,0,7,109,101,115,115,97,103,101>> ).
{"atom","message"}
```

It seems that the message is missing the 131 tag required by term_to_binary.  As is evident from the Java output, this tag is not being added by jinterface encode.  If I simply add 131 to the beginning of the binary it decodes correctly.

Now why is Java not adding it?

I will still accept answers as I have not officially answered my question ( in a supported way ie. not hacking with 131 )

Ref:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_ext_dist.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but if you're encoding `{atom, "message"}`, shouldn't you be sending over a tuple, not 2 objects one after the other?  Try creating a [Tuple](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/OtpErlangTuple.html) object and adding `atom` and `message` as elements.